# Wordpress Parent/Child user registration

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to evaluate the possibility of creating a plugin for Parent/Child functionality in Wordpress user creation.

What we need to achieve is to allow a Parent to create a sub-user account for his children. This accounts will have limited access but that can be done later with other Wordpress plugins.

What does not exist right now or what I was unable to find, is a plugin which gives the possibility to an existent standard user, to create sub-accounts related to him.

I do not want anything particular except the association between the accounts. The main user should have the possibility of adding or removing his child accounts.

Do you think this is something that is ok to do? Does it open us to any hacking possibility or vulnerability or create problems in the future?

If not, what would be in your opinion the best way to proceed and do this? What would be the best, fastest and most secure flow of operations?

Looking forward to your opinions.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this question because it's not a direct question regarding programming. It's a question that will have a broad opinionated response.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but here's an option for anyone searching for this in the future.

First, you need to register a new user role. When you register the role, you are free to assign any capability you want. In this case, give the new role the capability to add users.

Then you can create a one-to-many relationship between the new user role and the standard subscriber role. So the new user role can have many subscribers but a subscriber can only belong to one new user role.

This will do what you want. There are several plugins that can do this if you are not comfortable with coding which seems the case per the OP's question. You can try PODS which is free and available in the Wordpress Plugin Directory - https://wordpress.org/plugins/pods/.